# TypeError: lastrow.setValues is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy past a particular range to another spreadsheet serving as a database. The goal is to copy past values that are in the range(a43:n54), to the last row of the database page, then to clear the range (d11:n22) of the source sheet.

I've already used part of code I saw on another thread (the get/set values part). But here when I run the function, it says that **line 35 "lastrow.setValues(values) is not a function"**. I know it means my function is not valid and most likely it will do the same with all the `setValues` section...

```
function myfunction() 

{

// spreadsheet identification
const sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("page_url")

// identification of the ranges to copy and to delete 
const ws  = sourcesheet.getSheetByName ("Récap");
const source_range_to_delete = ws.getRange("d11:n22");
const source_range_to_copy = ws.getRange("a43:n54");

// get last row of target spread sheet
const destpage = destination.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
var destrange =destpage.getRange("A1:n").getValues();
var lrIndex;
for( var i = destrange.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    lrIndex = i;
   
    if(!destrange[i].every(function(c){ return c == "";})) { 
      break;
    }
} 
var lastrow =lrIndex +1;  

//get values 
var values = source_range_to_copy.getValues()
var bGcolors = source_range_to_copy.getBackgrounds();
var colors = source_range_to_copy.getFontColors();
var fontSizes = source_range_to_copy.getFontSizes();

 
// set values 
lastrow.setValues(values);
lastrow.setBackgrounds(bGcolors);
lastrow.setFontColors(colors);
lastrow.setFontSizes(fontSizes);

source_range_to_delete.clearContent({contentsOnly:true});


}
```

Comment: hello everyone *

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunction() {

  // spreadsheet identification
  const sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("page_url");

  // identification of the ranges to copy and to delete 
  const ws = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Récap");
  const source_range_to_delete = ws.getRange("d11:n22");
  const source_range_to_copy = ws.getRange("a43:n54");

  // get last row of target spread sheet
  const destpage = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  var data = sourcesheet.getRange("a1:n").getValues();

  for (var lastrow = data.length-1; lastrow >= 0; lastrow--) {
    if (data[lastrow].some(c => c != "")) break;
  }

  //get values 
  var values = source_range_to_copy.getValues();
  var bGcolors = source_range_to_copy.getBackgrounds();
  var colors = source_range_to_copy.getFontColors();
  var fontSizes = source_range_to_copy.getFontSizes();
  
  // set range right after the last row on destination sheet
  var destrange = destpage.getRange(lastrow + 2,1,values.length,values[0].length);

  // set values of destination range
  destrange.setValues(values);
  destrange.setBackgrounds(bGcolors);
  destrange.setFontColors(colors);
  destrange.setFontSizes(fontSizes);

  source_range_to_delete.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! had to fixe some few mistake i might have wrote in it, but seems to be working perfectly well indeed!

Answer (score 0):

setValues() is a method of class Range. lastrow is an integer.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, unfortunately i'm afraid that this first hint doesn't help me so much. would you have time to explain it a bit more ? if i don't ask too much

Comment: Your trying to set values from a single row of your data.  How do you identify that row as a range.

Comment: yeah i have figured it out, gonna have to study more my coding to go through it! thanks a lot for your help !!